# Add Series as a new row into DataFrame triggers FutureWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Trying to add a new row of type `Series` into a `DataFrame`, both share the same columns/index:

```
df.loc[df.shape[0]] = r
```

Getting:

> FutureWarning: In a future version, object-dtype columns with all-bool
> values will not be included in reductions with bool_only=True.
> Explicitly cast to bool dtype instead.

Which comes from [inference module](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/dtypes/inference.py).

Comment: Can you create a [reprex]?

Comment: Cannot reproduce have tried with: 

import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [True, False, True], 'col2': [True, False, True], 'col3': [False, True, True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.loc[df.shape[0]] = [True,False,True]

as @BigBen suggest, please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Indeed, just made a dummy example which is fine: import pandas as pd

# DataFrame
d = {'c1': [1, 2], 'c2': [3, 4], 'c3': [True, False], 'c4': ['abc', 'def']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

# Series
d = {'c1': 3, 'c2': 5, 'c3': True, 'c4': 'ghi'}
s = pd.Series(d)
s

# insert new row
df[df.shape[0]] = s   On it, there is some prop data involved...

Answer (score 17):

I got the same error and it is because of the [version 1.5.0 of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html) why maybe some answers are here not solving the issue:

> Deprecated treating all-bool object-dtype columns as bool-like in DataFrame.any() and DataFrame.all() with bool_only=True, explicitly cast to bool instead (GH46188)

So I tried to understand.. but somehow I was able to find a solution. The cause is that columns with boolean values are not properly casted. I used the concat and for me it was the existing DataFrame.

Because I don't want to define for all columns of the Dataframe the corresponding dtype (which might be also possible), I changed it for the necessary columns:

```
df["var1"]=df["var1"].astype(bool)
```

Or for multiple ones:

```
df=df.astype({"var1":bool,"var2":bool})
```

Then the concat worked for me without the FutureWarning.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured out this FutureWarning can be triggered by using `pd.concat()` on a dataframe with a boolean column and an **empty** dataframe.

Avoiding the operation if the dataframe was empty silenced the warning.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df
    c1  c2  c3      c4
0   1   3   True    abc
1   2   4   False   def

d = {'c1': 3, 'c2': 5, 'c3': True, 'c4': 'ghi'} 
s = pd.Series(d) 

s
c1       3
c2       5
c3    True
c4     ghi
dtype: object

df.loc[df.shape[0]] = s.to_numpy() 

df
    c1  c2  c3      c4
0   1   3   True    abc
1   2   4   False   def
2   3   5   True    ghi
```

Comment: Won't solve the issue.

Comment: why !? what is the required output ? this is based on the example of df and s you provided

Comment: The example was to show that is does not replicate the issue. In addition, I've tried .values, similar to what yo suggested.

Answer (score 0):

base:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'Name': ['Nik', 'Kate', 'Evan', 'Kyra'],
    'Age': [31, 30, 40, 33],
    'Location': ['Toronto', 'London', 'Kingston', 'Hamilton']
})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

|  | Name | Age | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Nik | 31 | Toronto |
| 1 | Kate | 30 | London |
| 2 | Evan | 40 | Kingston |
| 3 | Kyra | 33 | Hamilton |

solution:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'Name': ['Nik', 'Kate', 'Evan', 'Kyra'],
    'Age': [31, 30, 40, 33],
    'Location': ['Toronto', 'London', 'Kingston', 'Hamilton']
})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Using pandas.concat() to add a row
r = pd.DataFrame({'Name':'Creuza', 'Age':69, 'Location':'São Gonçalo'}, index=[0])
df2 = pd.concat([r,df.loc[:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
df2
```

|  | Name | Age | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Creuza | 69 | São Gonçalo |
| 1 | Nik | 31 | Toronto |
| 2 | Kate | 30 | London |
| 3 | Evan | 40 | Kingston |
| 4 | Kyra | 33 | Hamilton |

Comment: Using pd.concat won't solve the issue.

Comment: Seriously?
And why not? 

Try to explain in more detail what you need exactly.
Maybe sharing the code (or part of it that makes sense) will help more...

Answer (score 0):

happened to me as well when I search the message in google I got here.
the reason it happened to me:
when converting a dict to a data frame serious the conversion isn't converting a boolean type into: <class 'pandas.core.arrays.boolean.BooleanArray'>
it converts it to <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
.
so you need to convert it "manually" and than concat it, correct command that worked for me was:

```
_item = pd.DataFrame([dictionary])
_item["column"] = _item["column"].astype("boolean")
data_frame = pd.concat([data_frame, _item], ignore_index=True)
```

see also:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46662